# When was the paper of bitcoin announced?

Tags: history, satoshi-nakamoto, whitepaper

When examining about this, it is said that many are November 1, 2008, but on the other hand, there are sites that are on October 31st. Which one is correct?

Comment: Both might be true.  It can be simultaneously Nov 1 and Oct 31 in different timezones.  [An aircraft flight can arrive the day before it departed](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/flights-take-off-2018-land-2017-time-travel-auckland-hawaii-air-new-zealand-hawaiian-airways-taipei-a8136491.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the mailing list archives, the mailing list received [Satoshi's email](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2008-October/014810.html) at `Fri Oct 31 14:10:00 EDT 2008`. However the mailing list is moderated so perhaps the email was not received by everyone until a day later on November 1st. The [first response](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2008-November/014814.html) to the email was sent on November 2nd, so it may be that the email was not forwarded to the list for a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

According to the original source of Bitcoin, On 31 October 2008, a link to a paper authored by Satoshi Nakamoto titled Bitcoin, as a peer-to-peer electronic cash system was posted to a cryptography mailing list. He implemented the bitcoin software as open-source code and released it in early 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Archive.org say on dec 24 2008 : ***"Sat, 01 Nov 2008 16:16:33"***
[https://web.archive.org/web/20081224103053/https://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09959.html]

And Tim May (Cypherpunk) say (about the mail list creation in 1992) :  *John Gilmore and Hugh Daniel hosted the mailing list. There was no moderation, no screening, no "censorship" (in the loose sense, not referring to government censorship, of which of course there was none.) The "no moderation" policy went along with "no leaders."*

Comment: Some improvements needed in this answer: 1) Your link is broken. 2) You don't explain exactly why two different dates are given. 3) You could add a preamble to the last sentence to give it some context for people who read your answer first (the order is randomised in the main views)